# Виртуальная машина

Tags: yandex-cloud

Для работы с Яндекс Облаком (интересует SpeechKit) в соответствии с этой (https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/cli/quickstart) инструкцией требуется загрузка виртуальной машины. Я следовала инструкциям текста выше, а потом столкнулась со следующей проблемой: (картинка) Или так:

> ERROR: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Request validation error: Subnet 'e2lvojhatdel838pa8nj' zone 'ru-central1-b' doesn't match instance's 'ru-central1-a'

Я не очень понимаю суть проблемы. В чём дело и как её решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так как была выбрана подсеть central-b при создании машины тоже можно её выбрать, добавить

```
--zone ru-central1-b \
```

Answer (score 1):

Для использования SpeechKit не обязательно наличие машины в облаке и даже cli не обязательно активировать.
Авторизация, кратно, описывается в [документации SpeechKit](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/concepts/auth). Достаточно подробные примеры можно найти там же: [тут](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/tts/request#examples) и [тут](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/stt/transcribation#examples).